# User can´t add a comment to a sharepoint list item (in the default comment pannel, that is, that one from microsoft)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, bug, comments

A user has recently reported me a problem involving not being able to add a comment to an item in a sharepoint online list. she opened the item form (I guess it was a view one, though it might have been the edit/create form), oppened the comment pannel and unsuccessfully tried to add a new comment. More precisely, when she hit enter to insert the new comment, the comment input box disappeared - just like it normally would - but the comment did not show up bellow, even when you inspect the item at a later time (I mean, it seems like it was really not inserted).

Details I´d like to point out:

- The user in question has all necessary privilages to add/delete/edit/view any item on the list
- the list form has been created using Power Apps
- I have tried to reproduce the problem on my machine and turns out I could totally add as many comments as I wanted
- I´ve fetched the comments related to that item through this endpoint: https://.sharepoint.com/sites//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('')/GetItemById()/Comments()     -----> and the comments she tried to add haven´t shown there either.
- I´ve got Total Control permission level.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please check if there is any error in browser console when she hits Enter to save the comment?

Comment: Whether this issue occurs in only one list or in all lists?